# wxWidgets and VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I decided to familiarize myself with wxWidgets today.
I downloaded version 2.8.9 (current release), and compiled the library in all the desired modes.

I am able to build/run the samples that ship with wxWidgets out of the box.
However, when I compile with **/Za** (i.e., language extensions disabled), I get over 100 build errors on even the smallest wxWidgets sample.

I am unable to find any documentation on this issue. Could I define something that will switch wxWidget's internals to be standards compliant (at least as far as VC++'s compliance goes)?

Perhaps I did something wrong while building the original library... Has anyone even encountered this "issue" before?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I'm using VC++ 9.

Also, here are the first few errors:

> ------ Build started: Project: minimal, Configuration: Unicode Debug Win32 ------
>
> Compiling...
>
> minimal.cpp
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(69) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(69) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(69) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(69) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(810) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SCMPFUNC'
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(810) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(810) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(811) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SCMPFUNC'
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(811) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> c:\wxWidgets-2.8.9\include\wx/dynarray.h(811) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

**EDIT:** It looks like the first error's caused by the fact that **_cdecl** is used. It looks like **defs.h** only checks if **__VISUALC__** is defined. Nothing about pedantism in sight...

Comment: Please post some errors generated by the compiler.

Comment: It would probably help to know which version of Visual Studio you have - each VC++ version has a different level of standards support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably find that you won't be able to build even a basic Win32 application, let alone a wxWidgets app, with `/Za`, because the Windows Platform SDK headers included with VS2008 use language extensions. The only solution is to disable `/Za`.

The specific error you're seeing is because the `_cdecl` keyword is a Microsoft extension, and not part of standard C++.
For more information, see the [documentation for `/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx), and the [Microsoft Extensions to C and C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx) and [C++ Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) pages in MSDN.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, the latest PSDK (6.1) builds with /Za without problems. As for the rest of your post, I'm well aware of how extensions work.

Kind of disappointing that wxWidgets doesn't support this. Oh well, thanks for confirming!